# How to change length of certain column of a dataframe in foreach() in R

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach

Suppose we have the following data set named `data2`.

```
id  v1  v2
1   5   0.5
1   4   0.5
1   6   0.5
2   2   0.2
2   3   0.2
2   7   0.2
2   8   0.2
```

Here is my problem: `length(data2$v1)` should change as the dimension of data change (splitted by `id`). For instance, for `id = 1`, `length(data2$v1) = 3` and `length(data2$v1) = 4` when `id = 2`. Using `foreach()` is a must in my case. How I can possibly do this? Any help is much appreciated!

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

foreach(i = 1:length(data2$v1)) %dopar% {
   a <- matrix(nrow = length(data2[i]$v1), ncol=2)
    for (j in 1:length(data2[i]$v1)) {
        for (k in 1:2) {
            a[j,k] <- j*k
          }
  }
return(a)
}
```

Comment: Can you create a function? Or do you need an outer `for` loop i.e. `for(id1 in unique(data2$v1)) {subdat <- subset(data2, id == id1); ...}` and then use the length from the subset

Comment: It is not clear about which way you want to follow

Comment: The `for` loop should be inside the `foreach()` & matrix `a` also depend on the `length()`..

Comment: The `i` seems to be vector, while you are calling `dim(i)`

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we wanted to apply the `foreach` separately on those `unique` 'id' rows, an option is either to `split` by 'id' or wrap with an outer `for` loop iterating over the `unique` 'id', then inside the loop, `subset` the data for that particular 'id' ('subdat').  Initiate a `list` ('out') to store the results of the `foreach` and assign the `matrix` output from the inner nested `for` loop

```
library(doParallel)

un_id <- unique(data2$id)
out <- vector('list', length(un_id))
names(out) <- un_id
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(length(un_id)))
for(id1 in un_id) {
    subdat <- subset(data2, id == id1)
    out[[id1]] <- foreach(i = seq_len(nrow(subdat))) %dopar% {
      a <- matrix(nrow = nrow(subdat), ncol=2)
       for (j in seq(i)) {
         for (k in 1:2) {
             a[j,k] <- j*k
          }
        }
        a
     }
     
  
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Tnx @akrun. I think both `seq_len(nrow(subdat))` and `seq(i)` should be changed into `nrow(subdat)` in my case. How do I possibly combine those `lists` into a single data frame?

Comment: @Gada  It is based on your code `1:length` and `nrow(subdat)` is just a single value.  You can use `do.call(rbind, out)` or `rbindlist(out)` from `data.table`

Comment: I have tried (`do.call(rbind,out))`. But I was not successful & gives me some weird result. I don't know where I lost!

Comment: @Gada It could be because of different column names.  Try with `rbindlist` or `bind_rows`